# Django, When to use multiple template loaders

Tags: django, django-templates

This is a standard practice question

So I have a Django app that contains the standard loader that loads all my web templates from the `assets/template` folder along with most expected context processors.
My app also sends out e-mails in txt and html formats for which I use a different loader. The loaders are set up as follows:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages'
            ],
        },
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'EmailTemplates',
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets/mails')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
    },
]
```

When rendering the mails I use `get_template(..., using='EmailTemplates') and it works fine. However, my partner argues that the differences between the loaders are minimal and that it's better to make it just one loader and place`assets/mails`to`assets/templates/mails`.

As Django was build to support multiple template loaders (as evident by the parameters `using` in the many key template methods, I was wondering:

**When is it useful to implement multiple template loaders on a site and when should it be avoided?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say that you'd like to use jinja2 in your application. Perhaps you are trying to quickly migrate a project from Flask to Django, or perhaps you prefer Jinja2's features over the features of Django's built-in template engine. Since Django itself uses its own template engine for /admin, and since you probably want to leave that alone, an easy and safe path is to enable both template engines along the lines documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/templates/#usage).

Comment: So what you are saying is that it is useful when using templates that adhere a different template engine originally (such as jinja2). However, what if you start the project from the beginning in Django?
In my situation, I wanted to use a different template loader in order to store the template files elsewhere without conflicts while also implementing unique context processors. Would that be a valid reason in your opinion or only clutter the project?

Comment: In addition to addressing the title question I was trying to provide a clear example of when it is useful or manditory to implement multiple template loaders. Your case is perhaps more subtle; I can see how you and your partner might differ in opinion. Consider this: we've all received broken html email, the likely result of a designer getting carried away with the available features of a templating engine. Clear your context processors down to a base minimum for email templates and you prevent the slew of unsubscibes that follow any munged email blast. Reason enough to go with your setup.